# How can I add a CSS class to the body tag based on the current path alias?

Tags: theming, 8

Is it possible in Drupal 8, to add a CSS class to the `<body>` tag based on the current path alias?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your theme, you can add the following code in `template_preprocess_html`:

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$path_alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
$path_alias = ltrim($path_alias, '/');
$variables['attributes']['class'][] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($path_alias);
```

Comment: **Thanks for the solution.**